# sprite.svg not displaying icons when deployed to Heroku but working locally (Django, Heroku, SVG)

Tags: django, heroku, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I am coding a landing page using Django, html, CSS.
I have a sprite.svg file containing different icons(svg drawings which can be accessed using "" for instance).
The sprite.svg file is located in my static file.
When I launch the page on my local server the icons appear with no problem.
When I deploy to heroku the icons are not showing.
Could you please help me with this problem?

The architecture is the following

```
django project
-----main app
----------settings.py
----------urls.py
-----second app
     -----static
----------css
----------img
---------------sprite.svg
----------js
-----templates
----------secondapp
---------------index.html
-----manage.py
-----Procfile
```

The settings.py file:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import django_heroku

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [...]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main_app',
    'lp001',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'leadinsightmarketing.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR, ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'leadinsightmarketing.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': '...',
        'HOST': '...',
        'PORT': '...',
    }
}


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    ...
]

ACTIVE_CAMPAIGN_URL = '...'
ACTIVE_CAMPAIGN_KEY = '...'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

The sprite.svg file:

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<symbol id="icon-chevron-thin-down" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M17.418 6.109c0.272-0.268 0.709-0.268 0.979 0s0.271 0.701 0 0.969l-7.908 7.83c-0.27 0.268-0.707 0.268-0.979 0l-7.908-7.83c-0.27-0.268-0.27-0.701 0-0.969s0.709-0.268 0.979 0l7.419 7.141 7.418-7.141z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-layers" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M9.248 11.601c0.45 0.313 1.050 0.313 1.5 0l9.088-5.281c0.236-0.164 0.21-0.518-0.048-0.646l-9.205-3.537c-0.368-0.183-0.802-0.183-1.17 0l-9.205 3.537c-0.258 0.127-0.284 0.482-0.048 0.646l9.088 5.281zM19.788 10.811l-2.486-1.233-5.725 3.327c-0.469 0.309-1.014 0.471-1.579 0.471s-1.11-0.163-1.579-0.471l-5.721-3.329-2.49 1.234c-0.258 0.128-0.284 0.482-0.048 0.646l9.088 6.309c0.45 0.313 1.050 0.313 1.5 0l9.088-6.309c0.236-0.163 0.21-0.517-0.048-0.645z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-address" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M19.799 5.165l-2.375-1.83c-0.135-0.093-0.324-0.176-0.521-0.237-0.198-0.061-0.403-0.098-0.567-0.098h-6.836l0.801 5h6.035c0.164 0 0.369-0.037 0.566-0.098s0.387-0.145 0.521-0.236l2.375-1.832c0.135-0.091 0.202-0.212 0.202-0.334s-0.067-0.243-0.201-0.335zM8.5 1h-1c-0.276 0-0.5 0.224-0.5 0.5v3.5h-3.336c-0.166 0-0.37 0.037-0.567 0.099-0.198 0.060-0.387 0.143-0.521 0.236l-2.375 1.83c-0.135 0.091-0.201 0.213-0.201 0.335s0.066 0.242 0.201 0.335l2.375 1.832c0.134 0.091 0.323 0.175 0.521 0.235s0.401 0.098 0.567 0.098h3.336v8.5c0 0.276 0.224 0.5 0.5 0.5h1c0.276 0 0.5-0.224 0.5-0.5v-17c0-0.276-0.224-0.5-0.5-0.5z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-bell" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M14.65 8.512c-2.28-4.907-3.466-6.771-7.191-6.693-1.327 0.027-1.009-0.962-2.021-0.587-1.010 0.375-0.143 0.924-1.177 1.773-2.902 2.383-2.635 4.587-1.289 9.84 0.567 2.213-1.367 2.321-0.602 4.465 0.559 1.564 4.679 2.219 9.025 0.607s7.086-4.814 6.527-6.378c-0.765-2.145-2.311-0.961-3.272-3.027zM10.924 16.595c-3.882 1.44-7.072 0.594-7.207 0.217-0.232-0.65 1.253-2.816 5.691-4.463s6.915-1.036 7.174-0.311c0.153 0.429-1.775 3.116-5.658 4.557zM9.676 13.101c-2.029 0.753-3.439 1.614-4.353 2.389 0.643 0.584 1.847 0.726 3.046 0.281 1.527-0.565 2.466-1.866 2.095-2.904-0.005-0.013-0.011-0.023-0.016-0.036-0.251 0.082-0.508 0.171-0.772 0.27z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-compass" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M5.454 14.548c0 0 4.568-0.627 6.518-2.576s2.576-6.518 2.576-6.518-4.569 0.627-6.518 2.576-2.576 6.518-2.576 6.518zM9.017 9.015c0.818-0.818 2.385-1.4 3.729-1.762-0.361 1.342-0.945 2.92-1.76 3.732-0.543 0.545-1.426 0.545-1.969 0-0.545-0.543-0.545-1.425 0-1.97zM10.001 0.4c-5.303 0-9.601 4.298-9.601 9.6 0 5.303 4.298 9.601 9.601 9.601 5.301 0 9.6-4.298 9.6-9.601s-4.299-9.6-9.6-9.6zM10 17.6c-4.197 0-7.6-3.402-7.6-7.6 0-4.197 3.402-7.6 7.6-7.6 4.197 0 7.601 3.402 7.601 7.6 0 4.197-3.404 7.6-7.601 7.6z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-credit" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M11 16.755v2.245h-2v-2.143c-1.712-0.1-3.066-0.589-4.241-1.797l1.718-1.74c0.859 0.87 2.023 1.16 3.282 1.16 1.565 0 2.405-0.599 2.405-1.702 0-0.483-0.133-0.889-0.42-1.16-0.267-0.251-0.572-0.387-1.202-0.483l-1.642-0.232c-1.164-0.174-2.022-0.541-2.634-1.141-0.648-0.657-0.973-1.546-0.973-2.707 0-2.155 1.382-3.743 3.707-4.1v-1.955h2v1.932c1.382 0.145 2.465 0.62 3.415 1.551l-1.679 1.682c-0.859-0.832-1.889-0.947-2.787-0.947-1.412 0-2.099 0.792-2.099 1.74 0 0.348 0.115 0.716 0.401 0.986 0.267 0.252 0.706 0.464 1.26 0.541l1.602 0.232c1.241 0.174 2.023 0.522 2.596 1.063 0.726 0.696 1.050 1.702 1.050 2.92 0 2.25-1.567 3.662-3.759 4.055z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-drop" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M10.203 0.561c-0.027-0.215-0.38-0.215-0.406 0-0.883 7.107-5.398 8.572-5.398 13.512 0 3.053 2.564 5.527 5.601 5.527s5.6-2.475 5.6-5.527c0-4.94-4.514-6.405-5.397-13.512zM9.35 8.418c-0.059 0.219-0.123 0.444-0.189 0.678-0.401 1.424-0.856 3.039-0.856 4.906 0 1.012-0.598 1.371-1.156 1.371-0.639 0-1.156-0.523-1.156-1.166 0-2.207 1.062-3.649 2-4.92 0.295-0.398 0.572-0.775 0.797-1.15 0.103-0.172 0.38-0.164 0.506 0.006 0.059 0.080 0.079 0.182 0.054 0.275z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-emoji-happy" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M10 0.4c-5.302 0-9.6 4.298-9.6 9.6s4.298 9.6 9.6 9.6c5.301 0 9.6-4.298 9.6-9.601 0-5.301-4.299-9.599-9.6-9.599zM10 17.599c-4.197 0-7.6-3.402-7.6-7.6s3.402-7.599 7.6-7.599c4.197 0 7.601 3.402 7.601 7.6s-3.404 7.599-7.601 7.599zM7.501 9.75c0.828 0 1.499-0.783 1.499-1.75s-0.672-1.75-1.5-1.75-1.5 0.783-1.5 1.75 0.672 1.75 1.501 1.75zM12.5 9.75c0.829 0 1.5-0.783 1.5-1.75s-0.672-1.75-1.5-1.75-1.5 0.784-1.5 1.75 0.672 1.75 1.5 1.75zM14.341 11.336c-0.363-0.186-0.815-0.043-1.008 0.32-0.034 0.066-0.869 1.593-3.332 1.593-2.451 0-3.291-1.513-3.333-1.592-0.188-0.365-0.632-0.514-1.004-0.329-0.37 0.186-0.52 0.636-0.335 1.007 0.050 0.099 1.248 2.414 4.672 2.414 3.425 0 4.621-2.316 4.67-2.415 0.184-0.367 0.036-0.81-0.33-0.998z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-globe" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M10 0.4c-5.295 0-9.601 4.307-9.601 9.6s4.306 9.6 9.601 9.6c5.293 0 9.6-4.307 9.6-9.6s-4.307-9.6-9.6-9.6zM18.188 10c0 1.873-0.636 3.6-1.696 4.98-0.3-0.234-0.619-0.867-0.319-1.523 0.303-0.66 0.382-2.188 0.312-2.783-0.066-0.594-0.375-2.025-1.214-2.039-0.838-0.012-1.413-0.289-1.911-1.283-1.033-2.068 1.939-2.465 0.906-3.609-0.289-0.322-1.783 1.322-2.002-0.869-0.014-0.157 0.135-0.392 0.336-0.636 3.244 1.090 5.588 4.157 5.588 7.762zM8.875 1.893c-0.196 0.382-0.713 0.537-1.027 0.824-0.684 0.619-0.978 0.533-1.346 1.127-0.371 0.594-1.567 1.449-1.567 1.879s0.604 0.936 0.906 0.838c0.302-0.1 1.099-0.094 1.567 0.070 0.469 0.166 3.914 0.332 2.816 3.244-0.348 0.926-1.873 0.77-2.279 2.303-0.061 0.225-0.272 1.186-0.285 1.5-0.025 0.486 0.344 2.318-0.125 2.318-0.471 0-1.738-1.639-1.738-1.936s-0.328-1.338-0.328-2.23c0-0.891-1.518-0.877-1.518-2.062 0-1.068 0.823-1.6 0.638-2.113-0.181-0.51-1.627-0.527-2.23-0.59 1.053-2.731 3.53-4.758 6.516-5.172zM7.424 17.77c0.492-0.26 0.542-0.596 0.988-0.613 0.51-0.023 0.925-0.199 1.5-0.326 0.51-0.111 1.423-0.629 2.226-0.695 0.678-0.055 2.015 0.035 2.375 0.689-1.295 0.861-2.848 1.363-4.514 1.363-0.899 0-1.765-0.149-2.575-0.418z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-graduation-cap" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M3.302 12.238c0.464 1.879 1.054 2.701 3.022 3.562 1.969 0.86 2.904 1.8 3.676 1.8s1.648-0.822 3.616-1.684c1.969-0.861 1.443-1.123 1.907-3.002l-5.523 2.686-6.698-3.362zM19.511 7.336l-8.325-4.662c-0.652-0.365-1.72-0.365-2.372 0l-8.326 4.662c-0.652 0.365-0.652 0.963 0 1.328l8.325 4.662c0.652 0.365 1.72 0.365 2.372 0l5.382-3.014-5.836-1.367c-0.225 0.055-0.472 0.086-0.731 0.086-1.052 0-1.904-0.506-1.904-1.131 0-0.627 0.853-1.133 1.904-1.133 0.816 0 1.51 0.307 1.78 0.734l6.182 2.029 1.549-0.867c0.651-0.364 0.651-0.962 0-1.327zM16.967 16.17c-0.065 0.385 1.283 1.018 1.411-0.107 0.579-5.072-0.416-6.531-0.416-6.531l-1.395 0.781c0-0.001 1.183 1.125 0.4 5.857z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-heart" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M17.19 4.155c-1.672-1.534-4.383-1.534-6.055 0l-1.135 1.042-1.136-1.042c-1.672-1.534-4.382-1.534-6.054 0-1.881 1.727-1.881 4.52 0 6.246l7.19 6.599 7.19-6.599c1.88-1.726 1.88-4.52 0-6.246z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-leaf" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M19.025 3.587c-4.356 2.556-4.044 7.806-7.096 10.175-2.297 1.783-5.538 0.88-7.412 0.113 0 0-1.27 1.603-2.181 3.74-0.305 0.717-1.644-0.073-1.409-0.68 2.978-7.685 13.11-11.519 13.11-11.519s-7.149-0.303-11.927 5.94c-0.128-1.426-0.34-5.284 3.36-7.65 5.016-3.211 14.572-0.715 13.555-0.119z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-light-up" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M19 9.199c-0.182 0-0.799 0-0.98 0-0.553 0-1 0.359-1 0.801s0.447 0.799 1 0.799c0.182 0 0.799 0 0.98 0 0.552 0 1-0.357 1-0.799 0-0.441-0.449-0.801-1-0.801zM10 4.5c-3.051 0-5.5 2.449-5.5 5.5s2.449 5.5 5.5 5.5c3.050 0 5.5-2.449 5.5-5.5s-2.451-5.5-5.5-5.5zM10 14c-2.211 0-4-1.791-4-4 0-2.211 1.789-4 4-4 2.209 0 4 1.789 4 4 0 2.209-1.791 4-4 4zM3 10c0-0.441-0.449-0.801-1-0.801-0.185 0-0.816 0-1 0-0.553 0-1 0.359-1 0.801s0.447 0.799 1 0.799c0.184 0 0.815 0 1 0 0.551 0 1-0.358 1-0.799zM10 3c0.441 0 0.799-0.447 0.799-1 0-0.184 0-0.816 0-1 0-0.553-0.358-1-0.799-1s-0.801 0.447-0.801 1c0 0.184 0 0.816 0 1 0 0.553 0.359 1 0.801 1zM10 17c-0.442 0-0.801 0.447-0.801 1 0 0.184 0 0.816 0 1 0 0.553 0.359 1 0.801 1s0.799-0.447 0.799-1c0-0.184 0-0.816 0-1 0-0.553-0.358-1-0.799-1zM17.365 3.766c0.391-0.391 0.454-0.961 0.142-1.273s-0.883-0.248-1.272 0.143c-0.108 0.107-0.593 0.592-0.7 0.699-0.391 0.391-0.454 0.961-0.142 1.273s0.883 0.248 1.273-0.143c0.107-0.108 0.591-0.592 0.699-0.699zM3.334 15.533c-0.108 0.109-0.593 0.594-0.7 0.701-0.391 0.391-0.454 0.959-0.142 1.271s0.883 0.25 1.272-0.141c0.108-0.107 0.593-0.592 0.7-0.699 0.391-0.391 0.454-0.961 0.142-1.274s-0.883-0.247-1.272 0.142zM3.765 2.635c-0.39-0.391-0.961-0.455-1.273-0.143s-0.248 0.883 0.141 1.274c0.108 0.107 0.593 0.592 0.7 0.699 0.391 0.391 0.96 0.455 1.272 0.143s0.249-0.883-0.141-1.273c-0.107-0.108-0.591-0.593-0.699-0.7zM15.534 16.666c0.108 0.107 0.593 0.592 0.7 0.699 0.391 0.391 0.96 0.453 1.272 0.143 0.312-0.312 0.249-0.883-0.142-1.273-0.107-0.107-0.592-0.592-0.699-0.699-0.391-0.391-0.961-0.455-1.274-0.143s-0.248 0.882 0.143 1.273z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-line-graph" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M0.69 11.331l1.363 0.338 1.026-1.611-1.95-0.482c-0.488-0.121-0.981 0.174-1.102 0.66-0.121 0.483 0.175 0.973 0.663 1.095zM18.481 11.592l-4.463 4.016-5.247-4.061c-0.1-0.076-0.215-0.133-0.338-0.162l-0.698-0.174-1.027 1.611 1.1 0.273 5.697 4.408c0.166 0.127 0.362 0.189 0.559 0.189 0.219 0 0.438-0.078 0.609-0.232l5.028-4.527c0.372-0.334 0.401-0.906 0.064-1.277s-0.911-0.4-1.284-0.064zM8.684 7.18l4.887 3.129c0.413 0.264 0.961 0.154 1.24-0.246l5.027-7.242c0.286-0.412 0.183-0.977-0.231-1.26-0.414-0.285-0.979-0.182-1.265 0.23l-4.528 6.521-4.916-3.147c-0.204-0.131-0.451-0.174-0.688-0.123-0.236 0.053-0.442 0.197-0.571 0.4l-7.497 11.767c-0.27 0.422-0.144 0.983 0.28 1.25 0.15 0.096 0.319 0.141 0.486 0.141 0.301 0 0.596-0.149 0.768-0.42l7.008-11z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-magnet" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M12.165 17.86c-0.028 0.309 0.217 0.584 0.545 0.611l3.985 0.326c0.329 0.027 0.621-0.203 0.65-0.512l0.311-3.287-5.18-0.426-0.311 3.288zM2.344 14.999l0.312 3.287c0.028 0.309 0.321 0.539 0.65 0.512l3.985-0.326c0.328-0.027 0.573-0.303 0.546-0.611l-0.312-3.287-5.181 0.425zM1.831 9.583l0.321 3.391 5.181-0.426-0.322-3.387c-0.007-0.082-0.011-0.166-0.011-0.25 0-1.555 1.346-2.82 3-2.82s3 1.266 3 2.82c0 0.084-0.004 0.168-0.012 0.25l-0.321 3.387 5.181 0.426 0.321-3.391c0.021-0.225 0.030-0.449 0.030-0.672 0.001-4.252-3.677-7.711-8.199-7.711s-8.2 3.459-8.2 7.711c0 0.223 0.011 0.447 0.031 0.672z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-medal" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M10 10c0.528 0 1.026 0.104 1.504 0.256l-6.077-9.115c-0.059-0.088-0.157-0.141-0.263-0.141h-3.556c-0.117 0-0.188 0.131-0.122 0.229l6.231 9.347c0.687-0.356 1.456-0.576 2.283-0.576zM18.392 1h-3.556c-0.106 0-0.204 0.053-0.263 0.141l-3.823 5.734 2 3 5.764-8.646c0.065-0.098-0.005-0.229-0.122-0.229zM10 11c-2.209 0-4 1.791-4 4s1.791 4 4 4 4-1.791 4-4c0-2.209-1.791-4-4-4zM12.112 15.117c0.062 0.064 0.052 0.158-0.022 0.208s-0.095 0.153-0.049 0.229c0.047 0.076 0.018 0.165-0.065 0.199s-0.125 0.13-0.095 0.214-0.017 0.165-0.104 0.181-0.149 0.101-0.137 0.189-0.051 0.158-0.14 0.155c-0.089-0.003-0.167 0.068-0.174 0.156s-0.083 0.144-0.169 0.123-0.178 0.031-0.203 0.117-0.111 0.124-0.191 0.085c-0.080-0.039-0.18-0.006-0.222 0.072s-0.134 0.098-0.205 0.043-0.175-0.044-0.232 0.024-0.151 0.068-0.209 0-0.162-0.079-0.232-0.024-0.162 0.035-0.205-0.043-0.142-0.111-0.222-0.072c-0.080 0.039-0.166 0-0.191-0.085s-0.116-0.138-0.203-0.117-0.163-0.034-0.169-0.123-0.084-0.159-0.173-0.157c-0.089 0.003-0.152-0.067-0.14-0.155s-0.050-0.173-0.137-0.189-0.135-0.097-0.104-0.181-0.013-0.18-0.095-0.214-0.111-0.123-0.065-0.199c0.047-0.076 0.025-0.179-0.049-0.229s-0.083-0.144-0.022-0.208c0.062-0.064 0.062-0.169 0-0.234s-0.052-0.158 0.022-0.208 0.095-0.153 0.049-0.229c-0.047-0.076-0.018-0.165 0.065-0.199s0.125-0.13 0.095-0.214 0.017-0.165 0.104-0.181 0.149-0.101 0.137-0.189 0.051-0.158 0.14-0.155c0.089 0.003 0.167-0.068 0.174-0.156s0.083-0.144 0.169-0.123 0.178-0.031 0.203-0.117 0.111-0.124 0.191-0.085c0.080 0.039 0.18 0.006 0.222-0.072s0.134-0.098 0.205-0.043 0.175 0.044 0.232-0.024 0.151-0.068 0.209 0 0.162 0.079 0.232 0.024 0.162-0.035 0.205 0.043 0.142 0.111 0.222 0.072c0.080-0.039 0.166 0 0.191 0.085s0.116 0.138 0.203 0.117 0.163 0.034 0.169 0.123 0.085 0.159 0.174 0.156c0.089-0.003 0.152 0.067 0.14 0.155s0.050 0.173 0.137 0.189 0.135 0.097 0.104 0.181 0.013 0.18 0.095 0.214 0.111 0.123 0.065 0.199c-0.047 0.076-0.025 0.179 0.049 0.229s0.083 0.144 0.022 0.208-0.063 0.171-0.001 0.235z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-megaphone" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M17.223 7.030c-1.584-3.686-4.132-6.49-5.421-5.967-2.189 0.891 1.304 5.164-9.447 9.533-0.929 0.379-1.164 1.888-0.775 2.792 0.388 0.902 1.658 1.801 2.587 1.424 0.161-0.066 0.751-0.256 0.751-0.256 0.663 0.891 1.357 0.363 1.604 0.928 0.296 0.68 0.939 2.158 1.158 2.66s0.715 0.967 1.075 0.83c0.359-0.137 1.582-0.602 2.050-0.779s0.579-0.596 0.436-0.924c-0.154-0.355-0.786-0.459-0.967-0.873-0.18-0.412-0.769-1.738-0.938-2.156-0.23-0.568 0.259-1.031 0.97-1.104 4.894-0.512 5.809 2.512 7.475 1.834 1.287-0.525 1.025-4.259-0.558-7.942zM16.672 13.006c-0.287 0.115-2.213-1.402-3.443-4.267-1.231-2.863-1.076-5.48-0.79-5.597 0.286-0.115 2.165 1.717 3.395 4.58s1.124 5.167 0.838 5.284z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-moon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M13.719 1.8c0.686 0.385 1.332 0.867 1.916 1.449 3.42 3.422 3.42 8.966 0 12.386s-8.965 3.42-12.386 0c-0.583-0.584-1.065-1.231-1.449-1.916 3.335 1.867 7.633 1.387 10.469-1.449s3.318-7.134 1.45-10.47z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-star" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M10 1.3l2.388 6.722h6.412l-5.232 3.948 1.871 6.928-5.439-4.154-5.438 4.154 1.87-6.928-5.233-3.948h6.412l2.389-6.722z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-trophy" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M11.18 14.356c0-1.451 1.1-2.254 2.894-3.442 2.194-1.456 4.926-3.265 4.926-7.56 0-0.387-0.317-0.699-0.709-0.699h-3.43c-0.484-0.896-1.929-1.855-4.861-1.855-2.934 0-4.377 0.959-4.862 1.855h-3.431c-0.391 0-0.707 0.313-0.707 0.699 0 4.295 2.73 6.104 4.926 7.559 1.794 1.188 2.894 1.991 2.894 3.442v1.311c-1.884 0.209-3.269 0.906-3.269 1.736 0 0.994 1.992 1.799 4.449 1.799s4.449-0.805 4.449-1.799c0-0.83-1.385-1.527-3.269-1.736v-1.31zM13.957 9.3c0.566-1.199 1.016-2.826 1.088-5.246h2.51c-0.24 2.701-1.862 4.064-3.598 5.246zM10 2.026c2.732-0.002 3.799 1.115 3.798 1.529 0 0.418-1.066 1.533-3.798 1.535-2.732-0.001-3.799-1.116-3.799-1.534-0.001-0.414 1.067-1.532 3.799-1.53zM2.445 4.054h2.509c0.073 2.42 0.521 4.047 1.089 5.246-1.736-1.182-3.359-2.545-3.598-5.246z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-user" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M7.725 2.146c-1.016 0.756-1.289 1.953-1.239 2.59 0.064 0.779 0.222 1.793 0.222 1.793s-0.313 0.17-0.313 0.854c0.109 1.717 0.683 0.976 0.801 1.729 0.284 1.814 0.933 1.491 0.933 2.481 0 1.649-0.68 2.42-2.803 3.334-2.13 0.918-4.326 2.073-4.326 4.073v1h18v-1c0-2-2.197-3.155-4.328-4.072-2.123-0.914-2.801-1.684-2.801-3.334 0-0.99 0.647-0.667 0.932-2.481 0.119-0.753 0.692-0.012 0.803-1.729 0-0.684-0.314-0.854-0.314-0.854s0.158-1.014 0.221-1.793c0.065-0.817-0.398-2.561-2.3-3.096-0.333-0.34-0.558-0.881 0.466-1.424-2.24-0.105-2.761 1.067-3.954 1.929z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-facebook-with-circle" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M10 0.4c-5.302 0-9.6 4.298-9.6 9.6s4.298 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6-4.298 9.6-9.6-4.298-9.6-9.6-9.6zM12.274 7.034h-1.443c-0.171 0-0.361 0.225-0.361 0.524v1.042h1.805l-0.273 1.486h-1.532v4.461h-1.703v-4.461h-1.545v-1.486h1.545v-0.874c0-1.254 0.87-2.273 2.064-2.273h1.443v1.581z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-instagram-with-circle" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M13 10c0 1.657-1.343 3-3 3s-3-1.343-3-3c0-0.171 0.018-0.338 0.049-0.5h-1.049v3.997c0 0.278 0.225 0.503 0.503 0.503h6.995c0.277 0 0.502-0.225 0.502-0.503v-3.997h-1.049c0.031 0.162 0.049 0.329 0.049 0.5zM10 12c1.104 0 2-0.896 2-2s-0.896-2-2-2-2 0.896-2 2 0.896 2 2 2zM12.4 7.9h1.199c0.166 0 0.301-0.135 0.301-0.3v-1.199c0-0.166-0.135-0.301-0.301-0.301h-1.199c-0.166 0-0.301 0.135-0.301 0.301v1.199c0.001 0.165 0.136 0.3 0.301 0.3zM10 0.4c-5.302 0-9.6 4.298-9.6 9.6s4.298 9.6 9.6 9.6c5.302 0 9.6-4.298 9.6-9.6s-4.298-9.6-9.6-9.6zM15 13.889c0 0.611-0.5 1.111-1.111 1.111h-7.778c-0.611 0-1.111-0.5-1.111-1.111v-7.778c0-0.611 0.5-1.111 1.111-1.111h7.778c0.611 0 1.111 0.5 1.111 1.111v7.778z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-twitter" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M17.316 6.246c0.008 0.162 0.011 0.326 0.011 0.488 0 4.99-3.797 10.742-10.74 10.742-2.133 0-4.116-0.625-5.787-1.697 0.296 0.035 0.596 0.053 0.9 0.053 1.77 0 3.397-0.604 4.688-1.615-1.651-0.031-3.046-1.121-3.526-2.621 0.23 0.043 0.467 0.066 0.71 0.066 0.345 0 0.679-0.045 0.995-0.131-1.727-0.348-3.028-1.873-3.028-3.703 0-0.016 0-0.031 0-0.047 0.509 0.283 1.092 0.453 1.71 0.473-1.013-0.678-1.68-1.832-1.68-3.143 0-0.691 0.186-1.34 0.512-1.898 1.861 2.285 4.644 3.787 7.781 3.945-0.064-0.277-0.097-0.564-0.097-0.861 0-2.084 1.689-3.773 3.774-3.773 1.086 0 2.067 0.457 2.756 1.191 0.859-0.17 1.667-0.484 2.397-0.916-0.282 0.881-0.881 1.621-1.66 2.088 0.764-0.092 1.49-0.293 2.168-0.594-0.506 0.758-1.146 1.422-1.884 1.953z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-happy" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M16 32c8.837 0 16-7.163 16-16s-7.163-16-16-16-16 7.163-16 16 7.163 16 16 16zM16 3c7.18 0 13 5.82 13 13s-5.82 13-13 13-13-5.82-13-13 5.82-13 13-13zM16 18.711c3.623 0 7.070-0.963 10-2.654-0.455 5.576-4.785 9.942-10 9.942s-9.544-4.371-10-9.947c2.93 1.691 6.377 2.658 10 2.658zM8 11c0-1.657 0.895-3 2-3s2 1.343 2 3c0 1.657-0.895 3-2 3s-2-1.343-2-3zM20 11c0-1.657 0.895-3 2-3s2 1.343 2 3c0 1.657-0.895 3-2 3s-2-1.343-2-3z"></path>
</symbol>
</defs>
</svg>
```

The template of the concerned app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "lp001/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block body_block%}
<body class="main-container">
<div class="card">
        <div class="card-wrapper">
            <svg class="card--img">
                <use href="img/sprite.svg#icon-light-up"></use>
            </svg>
            <p class="card--text">blablabla</p>
        </div>
  </div>
```

icons showing locally:
[image: icons showing locally]

icons not showing with Heroku:
[image: icons not showing with heroku]

Thank you in advance

Comment: In the console log of your deployed version, the GET is returning `404 not found` so you aren't serving the sprite.svg file from production. So the problem is something in the way you've deployed it, you're either hitting an old version or have a permissions problem or haven't deployed what you think you have or something like that. It's a little hard to tell why from what you've posted but it looks like you've moved `index.html` to `lp001` in production so it isn't in the same place relative to the `svg`.

Comment: Hello, It was spot on I forgot to use {% static 'img/sprite.svg#icon-light-up' %}. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @I.M.Ice please be careful with your passwords and secret keys when sharing code and settings in public space.